# Bash - Piping output of command into while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, pipe

I'm writing a Bash script where I need to look through the output of a command and do certain actions based on that output. For clarity, this command will output a few million lines of text and it may take roughly an hour or so to do so.

Currently, I'm  executing the command and piping it into a while loop that reads a line at a time then looks for certain criteria. If that criterion exists, then update a .dat file and reprint the screen. Below is a snippet of the script.

```
eval "$command"| while read line ; do
    if grep -Fq "Specific :: Criterion"; then
        #pull the sixth word from the line which will have the data I need
        temp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ printf $6 }')
        #sanity check the data
        echo "\$line = $line"
        echo "\$temp = $temp"

        #then push $temp through a case statement that does what I need it to do.
    fi
done
```

So here's the problem, the sanity check on the data is showing weird results. It is printing lines that don't contain the grep criteria.

To make sure that my grep statement is working properly, I grep the log file that contains a record of the text that is output by the command and it outputs only the lines that contain the specified criteria.

I'm still fairly new to Bash so I'm not sure what's going on. Could it be that the command is force feeding the while loop a new $line before it can process the $line that met the grep criteria?

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: `eval "$command"` should be just `$command`. No need to use `eval` here

Comment: If you don't pass an input to `grep`, it will read from stdin. That means it will consume the whole output in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I originally had just "$command" but it didn't work correctly, so I did some googling and added the eval and it started behaving properly. I'm not exactly sure what eval does, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: Without the quotes, just `$command`. Don't execute a command when you are not sure what they are doing.

Comment: What hek2mgl says applies to all commands, and especially `eval`.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you match a string?  It seems likely that you should probably just be using `awk` instead of a `while read` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I added the (echo $line | grep...) that gbtimmon mentioned and it fixed it. I'm tempted to delete this question because it was a simple fix...

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm using sed to edit a data file, then executing a few functions that basically print a screen to display data to the user. I'm not sure how I could use awk to replace the while loop...are you thinking that it would just be faster somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does grep know what line looks like?

```
if ( printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -Fq "Specific :: Criterion"); then
```

But I cant help feel like you are overcomplicating a lot.

```
function process() { 
    echo "I can do anything I want"
    echo " per element $1"
    echo " that I want here"
}

export -f process

$command | grep -F "Specific :: Criterion" | awk '{print $6}' | xargs -I % -n 1 bash -c "process %";
```

Run the command, filter only matching lines, and pull the sixth element. Then if you need to run an arbitrary code on it, send it to a function (you export to make it visible in subprocesses) via xargs.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Oh man, that's embarrassing. Should I just delete this question?

Comment: I think its a fine question

Comment: I understand everything you said up until xargs. I'm not familiar with that. I'll read up and see if it's an easier solution. Thanks!

Comment: Oh no, you definitely should not delete a question if the accepted solution happens to be completely different compared to what you initially expected. The answer and even the question itself may contain useful information for other users.

Answer (score 1):

What are you applying the grep on ?

Modify

`if grep -Fq "Specific :: Criterion"; then`

as below

```
if ( echo $line | grep -Fq "Specific :: Criterion" ); then
```

Comment: Why do you repeat this answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721856/171318

Comment: Oops ! By the time I finished typing my answer, you had already answered it ! I'm using the stack overflow Android application .. unfortunately it doesn't refresh

Comment: I see. I was thinking something like that. That's why I was asking. ;)